# Django annotate returned more than one

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

```
user = get_object_or_404(
    (User.objects
        .annotate(company_name=F('usercompany__company__company_name'))
        .annotate(project=F('team__vacancy__name'))),
    email=request.GET.get('user_email')
)
```

I got errors:

```
proj.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2!
```

How can I change `.annotate(project=F('team__vacancy__name')))` to get all.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `prefetch_related` to fetch the vacancies. Depending on your models, the queryset would look something like:

```
User.objects.annotate(company_name=F('usercompany__company__company_name')
    ).select_related('team'
    ).prefetch_related('team__vacancy')
```

Then you can get the names with:

```
names = [v.name for v in user.team.vacancy_set.all()]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `get_object_or_404` it expects an object. Otherwise it returns HTTP status code 404 (NOT FOUND).

If you're expecting more than one object to be returned from the query, then you should use `get_list_or_404`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404
```

As it is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404) the difference between `get_list_or_404` and `get_object_or_404` is equivalent to the difference between `.filter()` and `.get()`.